# AltBeacon ranging never returns more than 1 beacon

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I'm working with the AltBeacon library (2.5.1) to detect beacons.
I setup ranging with an "universal" Region to be able to detect any beacon in range, then do my stuff with it.
The issue is that when I have several beacons in range, the  didRangeBeaconsInRegion callback always provides me a Collection of only 1 beacon at a time and this beacon is a random one among all the present beacons... Why can't I get all the beacons in range in my Collection ?

All of this is made from within a Service, I did clean all the other stuff to keep only the relevant parts of the code below -> Hopefully I am doing something wrong here ?

```
public class MonitorService extends Service implements BeaconConsumer 
{

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        super.onCreate();


        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

        beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(5000l);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5000l);
        beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(1100l);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(1100l);


        setupBeaconManager();
    }


    private void setupBeaconManager()
    {
        if (!beaconManager.isBound(this))
            beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    private void unsetBeaconManager()
    {
        if (beaconManager.isBound(this))
        {
            beaconManager.unbind(this);

            try 
            {
                beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("apr", null, null, null));
            } 
            catch (RemoteException e) 
            {  
                Log.i(TAG, "RemoteException = "+e.toString());
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() 
    {
        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override 
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) 
            {
                Log.i(TAG,"didRangeBeaconsInRegion, number of beacons detected = "+beacons.size());
                // HERE IT IS : the size is Always 1, but the beacon (UUID etc. can be different)
            }
        });


        try 
        {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("apr", null, null, null));
        } 
        catch (RemoteException e) 
        {  
            Log.i(TAG, "RemoteException = "+e.toString());
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        unsetBeaconManager();

        super.onDestroy();
    }


}
```

I'm working on Android 5.1.1 with a Nexus 6 (but a Wiko cheap phone gives the same results). The beacons are setup to advertise every 600ms... But even with 100ms it also gives the exact same results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks OK.  A couple of thoughts:

- Try using an off the shelf beacon scanner app based on the same library like [Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dlocate%20beacon%20play%20store&pcampaignid=APPU_1_f7T7VfPHDoauyQTb26_IBA).  Does it detect all of your beacons simultaneously? If not, something may be wrong with the beacons or their configuration.
- Do each of your beacons have unique identifiers?  The library by default only detects multiple beacons if they have unique identifiers.

Comment: THANX so much David ! The beacons had all the same UUID... changing it make them all appear as they should.

Comment: @davidgyoung I have the same problem. The Locate app recognize 2 beacons while my app recognize only 1. the both have exactly the same identifiers. From where you take that info that the library " by default only detects multiple beacons if they have unique identifiers."

JBA how did you change the beacon identifiers?

Comment: You can also set Beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true); which tells the library to treat two beacons as distinct if they have different bluetooth mac addresses but the same identifiers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My beacons too had same eddyURL so the altbeacon library detected them only once per scan.